# Unable to install docker on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

Following the commands outlined [here](https://howchoo.com/g/nmrlzmq1ymn/how-to-install-docker-on-your-raspberry-pi#add-dockers-gpg-key), I am unable to install docker on my Raspberry PI 4 running raspbian buster.

Below are the commands I've tried in order:

1) `apt-get update`

2) `apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates software-properties-common`

3)

```
add-apt-repository \
       "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ \
       raspbian-$(lsb_release -cs) \
       main"
```

After running the above commands, I tried running `apt-get update`:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
Err:2 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo raspbian-buster InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 13.249.111.113 443]
Ign:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/raspbian 10 InRelease
Err:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/raspbian 10 Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 13.249.109.27 443]
Hit:5 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/dists/raspbian-buster/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 13.249.111.113 443]
E: The repository 'https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo raspbian-buster InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/raspbian 10 Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried appending the apt repository configuration directly to `/etc/apt/sources.list` with the following items (one at a time):

```
https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ raspbian-buster main
deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ raspbian-buster main
deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ raspbian-jessie main
deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ debian-jessie main
```

I noticed that the apt repository does not yet have a butler section.

Answer (score 5):

I think support for this is still early, but was able to work around the issue by appending:

`deb [arch=armhf] https://download.docker.com/linux/raspbian stretch edge`

to `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Uninstalled enerything and tried several times.

Finally i logged in with putty over ssh and installed it over ssh console and not on the Pi "console" itself (vnc).

And it worked. No idea why.

(can't remember, maybe I also rebootet the pi after update)